# Citing multiple figures

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, cleveref

I am using the `cleveref` package and in my document I want to cite 3 figures in plurals like: "Figs 1, 2, and 3".

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalise]{cleveref}
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{imagetest1}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{imagetest2}\label{fig:2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{imagetest3}\label{fig:3}
\end{figure}
\crefrange{fig:1}{fig:2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding an extra comma where you want to add "and" in the `\ref{}` command. In this case, write

`\cref{fig:1,fig:2,,fig:3}`

[image]

Comment: This answer is very useful. Thank you very much @Mullvadsungen.